model.fit not recognizing labels in tf.data.Dataset
I am creating a dataset by generator like this
tfds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(streamFromFile, output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(240,120), dtype=tf.uint16))

The model is an autoencoder that internally calculates the loss, so the training should train the model to match it's output to 0. Therefore, the "label" is always a scalar of 0.
To add labels to the dataset, I use it as follows:
def prepareLabels(x):
    return x, 0

tfds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(...)
tfds = tfds.map(prepareLabels)

for x,y in tfds.take(1):
    print("features", x.shape)
    print("label", y.shape)
# prints:
# features (240, 120)
# label ()


The model is built and compiled with MAE loss (to match the output to 0). During training, I instantly get this:
model.fit(
  tfds.take(10).batch(4),
  epochs=3
)

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
...
        is_last_dim_1 = tf.equal(1, tf.shape(y_pred)[-1])

    ValueError: slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node mean_absolute_error/strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](mean_absolute_error/Shape, mean_absolute_error/strided_slice/stack, mean_absolute_error/strided_slice/stack_1, mean_absolute_error/strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <-1>, input[2] = <0>, input[3] = <1>.

This looks to me, as if TensorFlow does not recognize that the tfds dataset supplies featuers and labels and it interprets it as a batch of 2 items ?!
My model summary looks like this:
(the input is an image with a single channel and the output is a scalar value that should be trained to be near zero)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 input_3 (InputLayer)        [(None, 240, 120, 1)]        0         []                            
                                                                                                  
...

 encoded (Dense)             (None, 200)                  40200     ['reshape_4[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
...
                                                                                                  
 reconstruction (Conv2DTran  (None, 240, 120, 1)          37        ['up_sampling2d_11[0][0]']    
 spose)                                                                                           
                                                                                                  
 score (ScoreLayer)          ()                           0         ['input_3[0][0]',             
                                                                     'reconstruction[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 81365 (317.83 KB)
Trainable params: 81365 (317.83 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________


Minimum Example
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def generator():
    for _ in range(1000):
        yield (np.random.random((240,120,1))*255).astype(np.uint16)

def addLabels(x):
    return x,0

tfds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(240,120,1), dtype=tf.uint16))
tfds = tfds.map(addLabels)

for x,y in tfds.take(1):
    print(x)
    print(y)


from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Input, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Layer
from keras.models import Model

class ScoreLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        return super().build(input_shape)
    
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]

    @tf.function
    def call(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        return tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(x-y), name="diffScore")/1000


def build_autoencoder():
    inputs = Input(shape=(240,120,1))
    
    x = MaxPooling2D((4,4))(inputs)
    x = UpSampling2D((4,4))(x)

    x = ScoreLayer(name="score")(inputs, x)

    outputs = x

    autoencoder = Model(inputs, outputs)
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-2), loss='mae')

    return autoencoder

model = build_autoencoder()
model.summary()

model.fit(tfds.batch(10).take(1))

If you need additional info, please comment!
Thanks in advance :)

The error message shows it's about the predictions. You seem to have a layer at the end that turns everything into a scalar. This likely does not cooperate well with the standard fit function (expecting batch and feature dimensions).

Thanks mate! That got me in the right direction. The solution was to add an axis=0 argument to tf.reduce_sum because I accidentally reduced the batch dimension as well... Since my label is also a scalar, I supposed the issue in the labeling process...
